# Handle PWA update with API changes

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA built with ReactJS and I have the NetworkFirst policy handled by Workbox, so when I update the front, the service worker detects a new version and download it in the background and this new version is applied only in two cases: when the browser is closed and opened or after 24 hours.

The problem comes when I need to change something in the API (django), for example I change the name of an endpoint and I need to change in the front too. When that happens, I make the release in both, front and back, but with the PWA if it last one day to make the update, during this day the app will be doing calls to an "old" endpoint so it will not work.

I would like to know how to handle this, a newer version of the API when the PWA is not updated yet, or if it is posible to force an update of the PWA when required.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Only make backwards compatible changes to the API. For example you have API v1 (example.com/api/v1/endpoint) deployed, deploy v2 (example.com/api/v2/endpoint) and new frontend that uses API v2. After some time has passed and usage of API v1 has stopped, delete it and have a new backend deploy.